# I have a mount problem

Tags: mount

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/data0
```

yields:

```
 mount: /mnt/data0: /dev/sda2 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

But both

```
lsof | grep /mnt
```

and

```
mount | grep /mnt
```

yield nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your checks appear to focus on `mount point busy` - did you also check whether `/dev/sda2 already mounted` (`mount | grep sda2` for example)?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `lsblk | grep -i sda2` and `df | grep -i sda2`.